# How can I define the type of a field dynamically in a Symfony Form?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I'm building an application that allows the user to generate a form (Questionnaire) by defining a question and the required response field type. I store the question and the type of the answer (text, number etc) in a questionsEntity.

```
 $builder
            ->add('questionString')
            ->add('fieldType');
```

Now I need to generate a questionnaire from these questions. But I don't know how to create the field in the questionnaire form whose type can be set dynamically based on the value from the database. i want to do something like this with the Questionnaire Form.

```
        $builder
            ->add('questionField', TextType::class, array(
                'attr' => array('read-only' => true)
            ))
            ->add('response', $question->getFieldType());
    }
```

This obviously does not work. I think it might have worked in Symfony2 when strings could be used to identify the field type.

Is there any premade method to achieve this? If not, can someone point me in the right direction. I'm using Symfony5.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The field type parameter is indeed a string (i.e. `TextType::class` returns a string). Does `$question->getFieldType()` return a _fully qualified class name_?

Comment: @Arleigh Hix Oh I haven't tried returning FQCN. I'll try that and let you know. But is there a cleaner solution? Or is there anyway to implement this in a clean way?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by  using  Form Events

https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html

Comment: You are correct in that events are needed but link only answers tend to be frowned upon.  Consider updating your answer with some relevant question based code or else use a comment.